# Glucose spatial arrangement

Tags: organic-chemistry

It was written in my textbook that the spatial arrangement of hydroxy groups was determined by Fischer by studying certain properties. But I wanted to know to how the relative configurations of hydroxy groups were determined.
Glucose is dextrorotatary but that could be possible with many arrangements.

Comment: The full description is probably too long for an answer, and you should look it up. The basic idea is that one can build bigger sugars from smaller sugars. Once you establish the stereochemistry of the smaller sugar, you can use it to deduce the stereochemistry of the more complex sugars by examining what larger sugars can built from smaller ones via simple reactions.

Answer (score 1):

It's not *certain properties*, but a very careful observation if and with what products glucose reacts to other chemicals. Took many years. And even then Fischer did not know the absolute configuration, because at his time nobody knew the absolute configuration of *anything*.

Only when the first absolute configurations were known from X-ray diffraction experiments, one could start comparing.

Today we can calculate the absolute optical activity via quantum mechanics, but Fischer solved the Glucose structure in 1891, that's a quarter century *before* quantum mechanics.